# Adding a dll file to GAC in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: .net, tridion, tridion-2011

I have created a .dll project and I want to add it to Global Assembly Cache of Tridion server.

Consider I have the .dll at location "C:\Documents and Settings\myfunction.dll".

I have some questions.

1. Do I need to download the gacutil.exe from server or gacutil.exe present in my local machine is enough?
2. If gacutil.exe present in my local machine enough, do I need to change any configuration files?
3. What set of commands do I need to use in gacutil.exe?
4. Is there documentation available for it in SDL Tridion Live documentation?

Comment: This is not a Tridion question... Do take into consideration that often GacUtil is not present on production servers and the Microsoft recommended way to add assemblies to the Global Assembly Cache is to use an installer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really a Tridion question, but more a .NET question.

But you do need to run 'gacutil.exe' on the server where you want to install the dll. (In your case the Tridion Content Manager Server)
Make sure that you use the right version of gacutil.exe. (32bits vs 64bits). 
Normally you don't have to change any config-files. But the config file for the gacutil.exe can be found in the same directory and is named 'gacutil.exe.config'

To install an assembly in the GAC, you can use this command: `gacutil.exe /i MyNiceApplication.dll`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to drop a DLL into the GAC is to simply copy or drag-and-drop it into the C:\Windows\assembly folder.  It's a special folder (actually not really a folder, but a set of folders that windows lets you manage from the this easy place).

You will need to make sure that your DLL is signed.  To sign a DLL, in Visual Studio go to your project properties and tinker around with the signing options there.  It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: This is correct for 32-bit servers. However, 64-bit servers have not one but 3 assembly folders. It is strongly recommended to use the gacutil. If it is not installed, you can download the Windows SDK.

Comment: I know of only two GACs (C:\Windows\Assembly and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Assembly). What's the third one?